# Ajax.BeginForm beforeSubmit event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC, is there a way to fire an onBeforeSubmit event when using Ajax.BeginForm? I'd like to validate some data on the client side and give proper feedback to the user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**OnBegin** is what you're looking for:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", 
new AjaxOptions() {
OnBegin = "alert('Replace with validation logic.')"
}))
```

### UPDATE

Something like this:

```
   function onSubmitFeedbackBegin(context) {
        if (uploading > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will it cancel submission of the form if I return false?

Comment: Yes, returning FALSE will cancel the action.

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameters to the onBegin callback??

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: OnBegin doesn't stop the form from submitting