# Ajax.BeginForm with BeforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have several Ajax.BeginForm on my MVC website. Meanwhile I need to handle the **beforeSend** event of my Ajax calls.

So the below code works for my manual jquery ajax calls, but it doesn't work with the Ajax.BeginForm helpers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function (xhr) {
        alert('');
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to handle the beforeSend event on the MVC Ajax.BeginForm?

-------------------------------------------**EDIT** -------------------------------------

I need the before send event since I want to change the request headers :

```
'beforeSend': function (xhr) {
    securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', securityToken);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877304/ajax-beginform-beforesubmit-event

Answer (score 4):

I think you are following samples from http://richiban.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/ This post does not address the support of Ajax form integration. I did some tests and found the solution.

I assume you use MVC4 with `jquery-1.9.1.js`, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and  `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` referenced.

Following is my code

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.DummyModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Parent"> 
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "BeginClient" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
            <div>First Name</div><div>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
            <div>Last Name</div><div>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BeginClient(xhr) {
            alert("posting...");
            securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', securityToken);
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            'beforeSend': function (xhr) {
                securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
                alert(securityToken);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", securityToken);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you need to leverage `onBegin` event, see http://johnculviner.com/ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-custom-arguments-for-oncomplete-onsuccess-onfailure-and-onbegin/ there is clear explanation what is the parameters for each event.

Then in your global attribute class, your code looks like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPostsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes authorization based on anti-forge token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">MVC pipeline filter context.</param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            // Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null
                    ? antiForgeryCookie.Value
                    : null;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this way you can still force to use anti-forgery token with Ajax form.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For `Ajax.BeginForm` you can use [AjaxOptions.OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new AjaxOptions() {
            OnBegin = "requestBeginHandler"})) {
    ...markup here...
}
```

**Update.** To add new request header you can do something like this:

```
function requestBeginHandler(ajaxContext) { 
    var request = ajaxCOntext.get_request();
    securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    request.get_headers()['__RequestVerificationToken'] = securityToken;
}
```

Comment: The before send is the same as OnBegin ? Since I need the before change to update the request header. Take a look at my question edit. Thanks

Comment: @hugohilario, no, these are different functions. I've removed the refactoring suggestion after realizing what your purpose is. Still you can access the request object and add a header - updated the post with possible solution. Although it is not tested, so some effort might be needed to make it work

Comment: I am testing your code, but what's the argument ``ajaxContext``?

Comment: @hugohilario, this is an object of type `Sys.Mvc.AjaxContext` defined in the `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` library. It is passed as an argument to the `AjaxOptions` client-side functions and allows to read and manipulate ajax request and response. Consider it as kind of a wrapper over XMLHttpRequest