# How to run JavaScript code on Success of Form submit?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net MVC web application. I want to run some code on the successful response of the API method which is called on form submit.

I have the below Code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("APIMethod", "Configuration", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "formID" }))
{

}

$('#formID').submit(function (e) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
e.preventDefault();
if ($(this).valid()) {
    FunctionToBeCalled(); //JS function
}
}
```

But `FunctionToBeCalled()` function gets called before the `APIMethod()`,  but I want to run the `FunctionToBeCalled()` function after the response of `APIMethod()`.

So I made the below changes by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567796/6527049) link. But now the APIMethod is getting called twice.

```
$('#formID').submit(function (e) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
e.preventDefault();
if ($(this).valid()) {
//Some custom javasctipt valiadations
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#formID').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formID').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            console.log('form submitted.');
            FunctionToBeCalled(); //JS function
        }
    });

}
}
function FunctionToBeCalled(){alert('hello');}
```

So I am not able to solve the issue.

Comment: just pass a param and use a conditional statement to determine if a value is available. once available perform action. `success: function(text){ if(text){ FunctionToBeCalled() } }`

Comment: `APIMethod` is getting called twice not the JS method `FunctionToBeCalled()`

Comment: add FunctionToBeCalled() function too..

Comment: @MohammedShafeek updated

Comment: add return false; before closing $('#formID').submit(function (e) { will sove..

Comment: after if ($(this).valid()) { }

Comment: @MohammedShafeek can you please post your answer

Comment: is your page reloading after ajax call?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek yes

Comment: Why do you need to use `submit` and `ajax` both at the same time ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn Html.BeginForm into Ajax.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552297/1823841)

Comment: Inside `onSuccess()` you can call your `FunctionToBeCalled()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some work on success, fail, etc. situation of form submission, then you would need to use `Ajax` call in your view. As you use `ASP.NET MVC`, you can try the following approach.

***View:***

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = $('#demoForm').serialize();
    //If you are uploading files, then you need to use "FormData" instead of "serialize()" method. 
    //var formdata = new FormData($('#demoForm').get(0)); 
 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DemoController/Save",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,
 
        /* If you are uploading files, then processData and contentType must be set to 
        false in order for FormData to work (otherwise comment out both of them) */
        processData: false, //For posting uploaded files
        contentType: false, //For posting uploaded files
        //
 
        //Callback Functions (for more information http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
        beforeSend: function () {
            //e.g. show "Loading" indicator
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $("#error_message").html(data);
        }, 
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#result').html(data); //e.g. display message in a div
        }, 
        complete: function () {
            //e.g. hide "Loading" indicator
        },
    });
});
```

***Controller:***

```
public JsonResult Save(DemoViewModel model)
{
    //...code omitted for brevity
    return Json(new { success = true, data = model, message = "Data saved successfully." 
}
```

**Update:** If SubmitButton calls a `JavaScript` method or uses `AJAX` call, the validation should be made in this method instead of button click as shown below. Otherwise, the request is still sent to the `Controller` without validation.

```
function save(event) { 
    //Validate the form before sending the request to the Controller
    if (!$("#formID").valid()) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it's giving same issue. `Save` is getting called twice.

Comment: Could you try tom remove `@using (Html.BeginForm("APIMethod", "Configuration", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "formID" }))
{}` block? Just try to use a plain `html form`?

Comment: and how the javascript function save will be called?

Comment: and If I remove the `html.beginform ......`line from my code. how `$('form').submit(` will be called

Comment: Are you sure that you tried exactly the same code in my answer? Because I always use that approach and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as follows.

```
$('#formID').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{    
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");          
      if ($(this).valid()) {              
          $.ajax({
              url: $('#formID').attr('action'),
              type: 'POST',
              data: $('#formID').serialize(),
              success: function () {
                  console.log('form submitted.');
                  FunctionToBeCalled(); //JS function                      
              }
          });    
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }                

});
```

Check the browser console for fetching error. The above code will prevent of submitting the form.

I think line $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form") were throwing error.
For that use you need to add the following jQuery libraries.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove razor form tag if you want to post your form using ajax call and add post api URL directly to ajax request instead of getting it from your razor form tag using id:

Here is the revised version of your code :

```
<form method="post" id="formID">
    <!-- Your form fields here -->
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Submit your form on button click like:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Configuration/APIMethod",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: $('#formID').serialize(),
            success: function () {
               console.log('form submitted.');
               FunctionToBeCalled(); //JS function
           }
       });
});

function FunctionToBeCalled(){alert('hello');}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Ajax.BeginForm, this article should help [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-onfailure/ ]

Comment: I have to do some custom validation in the javascript side also on form submit

Comment: This question should help you accomplish that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877304/ajax-beginform-beforesubmit-event

Answer (score -1):

The major thing here is that I didn't use a submit button, I used a link instead and handled the rest in the js file. This way, the form would nver be submitted if the js file is not on the page, and with this js file, it initiates a form submission by itself rather than th form submitting when the submit button is clicked

You can adapt this to your solution as see how it respond. I have somthing like this in production and it works fine.

```js
(function() {
    $(function() {
        var _$pageSection = $('#ProccessProductId');
        var _$formname = _$pageSection.find('form[name=productForm]');

        _$formname.find('.buy-product').on('click', function(e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          if (!_$formname.valid()) {
            return;
          }
          var formData = _$formname.serializeFormToObject();

          //set busy animation

          $.ajax({
            url: 'https://..../', //_$formname.attr('action')
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(content) {
              AnotherProcess(content.Id)
            },
            error: function(e) {
              //notify user of error 
            }
          }).always(function() {
            // clear busy animation
          });
        });


        function AnotherProcess(id) {

          //Perform your operation
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="ProccessProductId">

  @using (Html.BeginForm("APIMethod", "Configuration", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", name="productForm" id = "formID" })) {
  <li class="buy-product"><a href="#">Save & Proceed</a></li>
  }

</div>
```